# Alignment of Floating logo with Top Menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a header in which I have the logo on the top left of the screen. To the right of the logo and aligned to it's base, I want to put a top menu. I have not used any CSS frameworks, and all the HTML and CSS code is located [here](https://gist.github.com/2481640).

I cannot get the menu to align to the bottom of the logo (which has `float: left;`). Also, after testing the margin settings with a border on all elements (`border: 1px solid;`) successfully, the minute I remove the borders everything reshuffles, and I have to add `padding: 1px;` in order to keep them in place.

Could someone please take a look and advise me as to the correct application of the relevant CSS?

**EDIT:**
Please note that the code does indeed work. My issue is that it is a hack (essentially adding non-existent padding to get the job done).

Comment: you should create a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) with HTML and CSS to illustrate your problem

Comment: Why do you expect me to compile .scss just in order to see what your problem is?

Comment: I made a JS fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/pGrdU/, now what are you going on about?

Comment: @Miszy: I wrote my Sass code so that the ppl that are better than me in CSS can see if I've made a mistake in the code.

Comment: @MatthewDarnell: Thanks for the jsFiddle. My point wasn't that it didn't work. It was that I had to add a workaround by adding essentially a non-existent padding to get it to align properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would advise that you do is to absolutely position the logo and navigation containers and then set the position and sizes of each element to suit. This IMHAO is more robust and reliable that floating header elements.

ie in the css:

```css
header {
    width: 100%; height: xpx;
    postion:relative; /* This makes elements inside that have position:absolute act relative to the container, useful if you need to move it around */
    top:0; left:0;
}

#logo {
    background: blah; width:xpx; height:xpx;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px; left:0px; 
}

nav.top_nav {
    width:xpx; height:xpx;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px; left:[header width + some padding]px;
}
```

Of course if needed you can tweek the zeros for padding.

Comment: It took me a while to realise why you recommended this way. I left it and then came back to it after I did some other stuff and it made sense. Thanks for the help.

Comment: time off something always helps me. awesome!